# Combine multiple matplotlib figures into one

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, dicom

I have a function that takes an enhanced dicom file and does the following:

1. Use a for loop that creates a single slice from the dicom file and then index it into a smaller array around a set of six specks.
2. A second for loop that draws circles around the six specks and one for the background
3. Show the image with all the circles plotted and the current slice location.

When I call the function I can create multiple images that are displayed in separate figures. So, how can I combine all these figures into one? Ideally I want to display them in a 3x3 grid.

Here is my current code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pydicom # Used for opening DICOM files
import numpy as np # General mathematical package
from pylab import text

# Import DICOM files
filename = "U:/File location" 
ds = pydicom.dcmread(filename)

# Speck Locations
centerSpeck = (1690, 1477)
centerSpeck2 = (100, 100)
twelveOclockSpeck = (45, 84)
twoOkclockSpeck = (66, 148)
tenOclockSpeck = (136, 147)
fiveOclockSpeck = (157, 82)
sevenOclockSpeck = (102, 41)
backgroundSignalValue = (71, 63)

speckLocations = np.array([centerSpeck2, twelveOclockSpeck, twoOkclockSpeck, fiveOclockSpeck, sevenOclockSpeck, tenOclockSpeck, backgroundSignalValue])

# Function that draws a circle around a given pixel
def drawCircle(arrayToPLot, zeroIndex, oneIndex, specks, r = 10):
    x = speckLocations[:,1] # get x axis variables from the speckLocations array
    y = speckLocations[:,0] # get y axis variables from the speckLocations array
    for i in range(zeroIndex,oneIndex,1): # For loop, note that the function range is: range(start, stop, step)
        tempIm = arrayToPLot.pixel_array[i,:,:].astype(float) # Get one slice as float
        slicedArray = tempIm[centerSpeck[0]-100:centerSpeck[0]+100, centerSpeck[1]-100:centerSpeck[1]+100].astype(float)
        for x,y in (speckLocations):
            plt.imshow(slicedArray, cmap='gray')
            circle = plt.Circle((y, x),r, fc='none', ec="red")
            plt.gca().add_patch(circle)    
            text(10, 180, i, fontsize=12, color='red') # Print the current slice on the image

        plt.show() # Plot each slice with circles drawn around all the specks and the background signal value location

#Call the function  
drawCircle(ds, 33, 34, speckLocations)
```

Comment: Create a figure with 3x3 subplots. Then plot each image to one of the axes.

Comment: Could you give me a little more information about how to do that? I figured out how to create a figure with 3x3 subplots, but cannot get my figures into it. I am using the instructions from this page: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/recipes/create_subplots.html.

Answer (score 1):

In the following we'll use the [`plt.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) method to produce a figure and a grid of `axes`, the Matplotlib objects that someone understands as *subplots*...

Iteration on a 2D grid first give you a row of the grid, a second iteration on the row gives you the individual subplot. When we have singled out an axes, it's time to call your function (you have the responsibility to differentiate the data to plot because it's not clear from your question what you want to do) but with an additional argument, the current axes.

```
fig, ax_grid = plt.subplots(3,3)
for ax_row in ax_grid:
    for ax in ax_row:
        drawCircle(ax, ds, 33, 34, speckLocations)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

At the end we show the figure, calling `tight_layout` to get a better arrangement of the subplots.

---

Of course we have to modify the circle plotting function... first we add `ax` to the list of arguments, next we modify the calls to `plt` methods to use the methods of the `ax` object:

```
def drawCircle(ax, arrayToPLot, zeroIndex, oneIndex, specks, r = 10):
    ...
    ax.imshow(...)
    ...
    ax.add_patch(circle)
    ax.text(10, 180, i, fontsize=12, color='red')
```

Comment: Your answer helps me get closer to what I am looking for. However, when I run the function you gave me it plots all the pictures in every window and then stacks each picture on top of each other. The following picture is what happens when I try and plot three pictures into the grid:

Comment: In my anser I wrote _"you have the responsibility to differentiate the data to plot because it's not clear from your question what you want to do"_ — please write a better question and possibly you'll get a better  answer

Comment: Sorry for the miscommunication here, but I did see that in your answer and I am trying to understand how to differentiate the data to plot. So, let me try and clarify what I am trying to do. Each time through the for loop in the drawCircle() function a new picture is created with circles around the specks and the slice location of that picture. I am trying to get each individual picture into the 3x3 grid and in its own location. I cannot figure out why each picture is plotted nine times and stacked on top of each other. Could you please help me fix that?